# How to hide the value of a tag in Enterprise Architect documentation

Tags: enterprise-architect

I made a custom template on Enterprise Architect that is a slight modification of the requirements template that came with the program. I edited the template to make it that the value of a specific tag will also be included in the documentation.

**"Requirement Type: {Element.valueOf(******)}"**

However, not every element in my document has a value for that specific tag. Is there a way I can have that line show up only when the tag has a value? Or have the documentation say

"**"Requirement Type: none"**

if there is no value?

I am using EA version 8.0.860 from Sparx Systems

Comment: I believe there are more than one EA's could you point to the vendor you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I am using the EA from Sparx Systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **version 10**, there is a new feature called *Fragment Template*. You could move the specific part of the document that you would like to show/hide into a Fragment Template by performing the following steps:

1. Create a new Fragment Template
2. Configure the fragment, e.g.

   ```
   package>
   diagram>
   element>
   Requirement Type: {Element.valueOf(****)}
   <element
   <diagram
   <package
   ```
3. On the Document Options, go to Element Filter tab
4. Click Add Filter
5. On the drop-down Search On, choose TagValue
6. Check the Property, set Condition to "Equal To", and set the value as the Tag name
7. Check the Value, set Condition to "Equal To", and do not set the value
8. Check the Required, then press OK button to close Add Filters window. This means that if the Tagged Value has no value, it will not be shown.
9. Press OK button to close Document Options window
10. You may create more than one fragment according to your needs.
11. Import the fragment template into your main template.

---

But since you are using **version 8**, IMO the options that you have are:

1. Adding "Requirement Type:" text into every Tagged Value that has value
2. OR, adding "none" into every Tagged Value that has no value.

You could create an EA Script to automate number 1 and number 2, because those are repetitive tasks.